# INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION when sideloading an apk

Tags: android, apk, adb, android-tv

I have a video projector based on android tv 9, but it's very closed, there isn't a file explorer, app store ecc. Wifi adb it's enabled by default. i want to install an file explorer (or any other app) but when i try to install the apk it gives me this

```
adb install filemanagerplus. apk
adb: failed to install filemanagerplus.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION]
```

[image: error]

the apk it's android tv compatible. What i can do?

Projector name: surewheel sw10

Model (that i found on android tv about setting): NL5H00X_TP

Comment: Assuming that the app you try to install is a regular (non-system) app it might be the case that the Android system is not designed to install custom apps and thus does not have an app folder on it's user data partition. If you have root access you could try to install the app manually to `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app`.